# Moving element to left - CSS Animations

Tags: html, css, animation

I am using CSS Animations to create a simple Slideshow and I have become stuck at this one point. I have:

```
#Content #PresentationSlideOne {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: Blue;

    -moz-animation: PresentationSlideOne 4s ease 1 normal;
    -o-animation: PresentationSlideOne 4s ease 1 normal;
    -webkit-animation: PresentationSlideOne 4s ease 1 normal;
    animation: PresentationSlideOne 4s ease 1 normal;

    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay: 20s;
    -o-animation-delay: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
    animation-delay: 20s;
}
```

The keyframe:

```
/* #region PresentationSlideOne */
@keyframes PresentationSlideOne {
    from {
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    to {
        margin: initial;
        float: left;
        left: 0%;
    }
}
/* #endregion */
```

which is set to margin: 0 auto; originally, because it needs to be horizontally-centered. But in the keyframes, I need to move it `from margin: 0 auto;` `to left: 0%;` - no matter which way I go about trying this nothing happens.

How do I make a margin: 0 auto'd element move to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set:

```
position: relative
```

on the element you're trying to move.

EDIT:

Actually, the solution is more complex. I would suggest centering the image in a container element and applying the animation to the container.

Better yet, do a search on GitHub for something like "css-only carousels" and learn how existing projects solve this problem.

Comment: Oh damn it I'm such a retard. I should've picked up on that. That's what is different about the other elements that move. Thank you @Tim!

Comment: Ah, it still won't move.

Comment: The left property moves in relation to the original position of the element. So, 0% won't move it at all. Negative numbers move it to the left, positive to the right. But again, I think there are more fundamental issues with your approach.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, I will go check it out now. For the meantime, I have come up with a quick solution. I only planned on having 3 slides (for now) anyway so this solution fits really well. Have each slide 33% in width, don't center with margin: 0 atuo; just use margin-left: 33% instead which will make it "centered" - then, use `from { left: 0%; } to { -33%; }`. :-)

Comment: I will come back when I have enough reputation to up-vote. Thanks again for your help, Tim.